# Customize url from the_terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I used custom post types, custom taxonomies, and [Beatiful Taxonomy Filters](https://github.com/jonathan-dejong/beautiful-taxonomy-filters) to create a sortable archive of yoga poses at [dev.stretcheveryday.yoga/poses](http://dev.stretcheveryday.yoga/poses/).

Trying to go a step further and link to pose taxonomy archives from single poses. For instance; "[One Legged Bridge](http://localhost/stretcheveryday/poses/one-legged-bridge/) is a Moderate Supine Backbend" is displayed with

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?> is a <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'level' ); ?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'position' ); ?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'focus' ); ?></h3>
```

Almost working but the terms need /poses/ added to the URL's so that they link to the proper archives.

How can I prepend **/poses/** to the_terms urls?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It has crossed my mind that I'm working in the wrong direction and perhaps should be looking at url rewriting?

Comment: If you want all term archives to have `poses/` prepended, you should register the taxonomy with that value as part of the rewrite slug.

Comment: Works for the_terms single URL's but breaks the taxonomy filter with adding too many 'poses':    

*dev.stretcheveryday.yoga/poses/poses/level/gentle/poses/position/seated/* rather than *stretcheveryday.yoga/poses/level/gentle/position/seated/*

Comment: Sounds like an issue with that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

More complicated than I realized. May not be pretty but [it works](http://dev.stretcheveryday.yoga/poses/revolved-head-to-knee-pose/).

functions.php

```
function get_btf_link( $taxonomy = '', $post = false ){
if ( ! $post ) {
    global $post;
}
$url = get_post_type_archive_link( $post->post_type );
$terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy);
if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $url = $taxonomy;
        break;
    }
}
return $url;
}
```

single-pose.php

```
<?php the_title(); ?> is a
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/poses/<?php echo get_btf_link('level') ?>/<?php $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'level', array('fields'=>'slugs',)); echo strip_tags( $terms[0]); ?>">
    <?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'level')); ?>
</a>,
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/poses/<?php echo get_btf_link('position') ?>/<?php $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'position', array('fields'=>'slugs',)); echo strip_tags( $terms[0]); ?>">
    <?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'position')); ?>
</a>,
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/poses/<?php echo get_btf_link('focus') ?>/<?php $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'focus', array('fields'=>'slugs',)); echo strip_tags( $terms[0]); ?>">
    <?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'focus')); ?>
</a>
```